# How can I merge these two MDB Databases

Tags: database, ms-access, merge

I have two .mdb microsoft access databases that I need to merge. They were originally the same file, but two co-workers have been editting them separately due to a "I thought this was a shortcut to the real thing" issue. So all the tables, columns, and relationships are the same - its just some of the data is different now. I'd like to merge without winding up with any duplicates, but keeping all the unique rows of data. I've tried doing this natively in Access via `external data` / `new data source` / `from database` / `access` but this results in a `table` and `table1` scenario, which is not what I want. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After you merge the files and get your table and table1 scenario, you can use the access query wizard to create an unmatched query which will find the missing rows that you can insert into the main table.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/compare-two-tables-and-find-records-without-matches-cb20ad48-4eba-402a-b20d-eaf10a5d1cb4

Comment: I'm going to try this out now, looks like it may help. Thank you! I'll let you know if it works

Comment: So this goes over how to query the differences between `table` and `table1` but not how to merge, say, the differences from `table1` into `table`

Answer (score 0):

You might hate this answer for how manual and hacky it is, but if your excel knowledge is up to snuff, you can pull the data from both tables into excel and find the differences that way. Then combine them together and import back into the database, then make sure the datatypes are correct.

Depending on how your forms validate data coming in, and the type of data you're working with in general, this may or may not work. If you have good clean data coming in.

Make a new column that concatenates every field. Use this field to perform a remove duplicates. From there you'll have every row that is unique.

Answer (score 0):

1. First I would link the two files via references within vba editor.
2. Left join each table combos (in both directions i.e. t1 left join t2 AND t2 left join t1) to find the records missing from either. If you decide which one you are keeping maybe you dont have to do it in both directions. Insert missing records into the file youre keeping.
3. Script the forms, modules and reports using Application.SaveAsText acForm,"MyForm","c:\form.txt" and compare them using a tool like WinMerge. This will help you verify any code or objects changes.

   4. For future proofing this scenario - give both people either split front ends or separate files that have linked tables to the master db. Oh and give your access files a real db on the backend (oracle, sql server or mysql.... or any of them really).